# how to print the output in multiple lines

Tags: python

```
var1 = "arun"
var2 = "86"
var3 = 4
var4 = 29

print(100*(var1+var2))
```

in the above code in python, I am getting the output as a single-line
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxkLn.png)

I want it to be printed in multiple lines. what should I do to make it work?. I have tried using the \n escape character but I am not getting the required output.

Comment: Why doesn't `\n` work?

Comment: `print(100*(var1 + var2 + "\n"))`

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by "multiple lines"? Do you want to inject newlines every `n` characters?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: print(100*(var1+var2+"\n"))

Comment: @Zeitounator ok i will surely keep this in mind

Comment: @ArunAgasti: you can edit your question to fix this in the current one

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a `for` loop rather than string multiplication if your intent is to print the same thing 100 times; it'll consume less memory (not that 100 times a 6-character string is a lot, but with a larger number it could become significant), and it makes the intent more obvious to the casual reader:

```
var1 = "arun"
var2 = "86"

for _ in range(100):
    print(var1+var2)
```

If you really wanted to construct a single string with newlines in it, apart from inserting `\n` before multiplying:

```
print(100*(var1+var2+'\n'))
```

another option would be to use `str.join` with list multiplication:

```
print('\n'.join([var1+var2]*100))
```

or a generator expression:

```
print('\n'.join(var1+var2 for _ in range(100)))
```

or to do either of the above with the `sep` parameter in `print()`:

```
print(*(var1+var2 for _ in range(100)), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `\n` character:

```
var1 = "arun"
var2 = "86"
var3 = 4
var4 = 29

print(100*(var1+var2+'\n'))
```

Comment: actually thanks i was not using the bracket in the \n command and as a result it was not working

Comment: Or with an f-string: `print(100 * f'{var1}{var2}\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code mentioned by you, below is the output:

```
arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86arun86
```

As per my understanding of the question, the output expected is as below:

```
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
arun86
```

To get the above output, please use "\n" in your code as shown below:

```
var1 = "arun"
var2 = "86"
var3 = 4
var4 = 29

print(100*(var1+var2+'\n'))
```

Also, if you need "86" also to be printed in next line, you can use the below code and so on:

```
var1 = "arun"
var2 = "86"
var3 = 4
var4 = 29

print(100*(var1+"\n"+var2+'\n'))
```

And expect below output:

```
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
arun
86
```

Comment: thank you in future i will take care to ask the question in a more comprehensive way